# Blazor Page Combobox DataSource to async method

Tags: async-await, syncfusion, blazor-server-side

I have an issue where I need to set DataSource for a combo box to a service's Async method.

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5">
    <SfComboBox TValue="string" TItem="ProjectStatusViewModel" PopupHeight="230px" Placeholder="Project Status" FloatLabelType="@FloatLabelType.Auto"
                DataSource="@LookUpService.GetProjectStatuses()" @bind-Value="@_projectToEdit.Status">
        <ComboBoxFieldSettings Text="Name" Value="Name"></ComboBoxFieldSettings>
    </SfComboBox>
</div>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DesignTracker.Application.ViewModels.ProjectStatusViewModel>>' 

to 

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DesignTracker.Application.ViewModels.ProjectStatusViewModel>'   DesignTracker.UI.SyncfusionBlazorApp
```

[image: DataSource issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncfusion support here.

We have checked the provided code example and issue details. We suspect that the reported issue may be cased due to mismatch in the type of data source and `TItem` in your application.

Also, we suggest you to bind the async method inside the `OnInitialized` method instead of assigned to the tag helper directly to avoid the issues at your end.

We have prepared the sample for your reference and attached it below.

**Sample Link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/274346/ze/ComboBox_274346-1580423979

**[index.razor]**

```
<SfComboBox TValue="string" TItem="Countries" PopupHeight="230px" Placeholder="Project Status" FloatLabelType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs.FloatLabelType.Auto" 
            DataSource="@DataSource" @bind-Value="@val"> 
    <ComboBoxFieldSettings Text="Name" Value="Code"></ComboBoxFieldSettings> 
</SfComboBox> 
 
@code { 
 
    private string val { get; set; } 
 
    public CountryService DataService; 
    public List<Countries> DataSource = new List<Countries>(); 
 
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
    { 
        DataSource = await ownservice.GetDataAsync(); 
        this.val = await ownservice.GetPreSelectDataAsync(); 
    } 
}
```

**[OwnService.cs]**

```cs
public class CountryService 
    { 
 
        public async Task<List<Countries>> GetDataAsync() 
        { 
            List<Countries> Country = new List<Countries> 
        { 
            new Countries() { Name = "Australia", Code = "AU" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "Bermuda", Code = "BM" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "Canada", Code = "CA" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "Cameroon", Code = "CM" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "Denmark", Code = "DK" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "France", Code = "FR" }, 
            new Countries() { Name = "Finland", Code = "FI" } 
        }; 
            return await Task.FromResult(Country); 
        } 
        public async Task<string> GetPreSelectDataAsync() 
        { 
            string value = "AU"; 
 
            return await Task.FromResult(value); 
        } 
    }
```

**[Startup.cs]**

```cs
 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{ 
    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0); 
    services.AddRazorPages(); 
    services.AddServerSideBlazor(); 
    services.AddSyncfusionBlazor(); 
    services.AddSingleton<CountryService>(); 
} 
[WeatherForecast.cs] 
 
public class Countries 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
 
    public string Code { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DataSource is expecting an enumerable collection, whereas you are supplying it with a Task that will eventually supply that collection. Try changing it to `DataSource="@(await LookUpService.GetProjectStatuses()"` which might do the truck.

The second option is to set up a backing property on the Parent component that holds that collection, and make the service call programmatically to populate the list, as in within the `OnInitialized` method override.

Comment: OnInitializedAsync was the issue. I overrode the non Async one